# Replacement AC adapter for my CR-48?

Tags: power-supply, netbook, google-chrome-os, ac-adapter, cr-48

I managed to lose the AC adapter on my Google CR-48. Yeah, already, I know. I have a couple more places to check, but does anyone know where I could find a compatible AC adapter?

19.5v 2.0a is not the sort of thing Radio Shack carries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 19.5v 2.0a is not the sort of thing Radio Shack carries.

http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4413345#tabsetBasic

Adjustable output voltage: 9.5V to 20V, regulated. 50W